# Adding differences from a second list to another in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have a question regarding lists in Haskell. I know Haskell lists are immutable so in this case a new list would need to be created. However, if I had a list `[1,0,0,1,0]` and another list `[1,1,0,0,0]` is there a way for the result to be `[1,1,0,1,0]` where the second list adds on to the first. Is this a case of using a higher-order function like fold?

Comment: Why is the expected result not `[2,1,0,1,0]`? I think your main problem is that you do not have a clear specification of what the result should be. If you have that, the code that implements it should follow naturally.

Comment: It is not really clear how the output maps on the input. At first sight, you want some sort of "elementwise maximum".

Comment: Now that I think about it more I guess it would be closer to applying logical OR through the two lists.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the function you are looking for is [`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith)